# Why is delegatecall returning 0 and erroring?

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, delegatecall, brownie, governance

I'm working with OpenZeppelin upgradable proxies, as well as their governance. I have a `propose` function that looks like:

```js
 function propose(
        address[] memory targets,
        uint256[] memory values,
        bytes[] memory calldatas,
        string memory description
    ) public virtual override returns (uint256) {
        uint256 proposalId = hashProposal(targets, values, calldatas, keccak256(bytes(description)));

        require(targets.length == values.length, "Governor: invalid proposal length");
        require(targets.length == calldatas.length, "Governor: invalid proposal length");
        require(targets.length > 0, "Governor: empty proposal");

        ProposalCore storage proposal = _proposals[proposalId];
        require(proposal.voteStart.isUnset(), "Governor: proposal already exists");

        uint64 snapshot = block.number.toUint64() + votingDelay().toUint64();
        uint64 deadline = snapshot + votingPeriod().toUint64();

        proposal.voteStart.setDeadline(snapshot);
        proposal.voteEnd.setDeadline(deadline);

        emit ProposalCreated(
            proposalId,
            _msgSender(),
            targets,
            values,
            new string[](targets.length),
            calldatas,
            snapshot,
            deadline,
            description
        );

        return proposalId;
    }
```

Which is the same as OpenZeppelin's [GovernorUpgradeable](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable/blob/master/contracts/governance/GovernorUpgradeable.sol) contract.

Then, I'm calling the function from a proxy contract like so (in brownie):

```py
tx = proxy_governor.propose(
        [vote_token_address],
        [0],
        [
            encode_function_data(
                vote_token.transfer, account.address, 1000000000000000000
            )
        ],
        "I want to pay myself 1 token. ",
        {"from": account},
    )
```

- `vote_token_address` is an ERC20 address.
- `encode_function_data` is a way to turn the function call into `calldata`. That part outputs: `0xa9059cbb00000000000000000000000066ab6d9362d4f35596279692f0251db6351658710000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000`, which should be the ABI encoded data for calling transfer on an ERC20, and sending 1 token to `0x643315C9Be056cDEA171F4e7b2222a4ddaB9F88D`

I'm just trying to propose sending myself 1 token.

However, I'm running into this issue:

```bash
VirtualMachineError: Transaction reverted without a reason string: Transaction reverted without a reason string
Trace step 2517, program counter 862:
  File "/Users/patrick/.brownie/packages/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.2.0/contracts/proxy/Proxy.sol", line 38, in Proxy._delegate:    
    case 0 {
        revert(0, returndatasize())
    }
```

Comment: revert "without a reason" might be because of lacking funds on senders account, or running invalid opcode instruction. So, in your case, the error is not emitted by your requires, but by some other instruction

Comment: run debug.traceTransaction() and see what is the latest opcode executed, might give a hint

Comment: `DELEGATECALL` returns the return value meant by calling code, and pushes 1 on the stack in case of success, and pushes 0 on the stack in case of an error. The return value is a separate thing from the codes pushed on the stack